# InstallAnywhere 2011 - Disable Previous button from Install Complete Panel

Tags: installation, installanywhere

Is there a way to disable previous button from Install Complete Panel since I do not have access to this panel?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom class that implements `CustomCodePanel` and replace the standard Install Complete Panel with your custom version.

From within your panel, you can disable the Previous button.

Below are some links for more information:

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q000018

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q000190

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q000447

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q113699

http://developers-online.blogspot.com/2009/11/creating-custom-code-panels-using.html